# Card template problem in Anki, with missing field, but the field isn't missing

Tags: anki

I have an error on one of my old cards due to the newest update. The preview is telling me "there is no field named..." I do have that field actually. But for whatever reason, I'm still getting that error. I deleted the part in the template as the website suggests. And the preview changed to the normal card. I tried to save but I get an error that says. Card template 1 in note type 2 "name of note" has a problem.  See preview for more information. But the preview is fine! What is going on here? [image: Error message: Card template 1 in notetype '2. Mnemocis (For Radicals)' has a problem. See the preview for more information.]